# Teams Bot FileInfoCard Sharepoint Content URL Error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm building a Teams Bot following this [Teams File Upload Bot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-file-upload/java) example.

I'm trying to get a PDF file through, and have it responding back with the FileConsentCard followed by the FileInfoCard:

[FileConsentCard and FileInfoCard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST6dn.png)

When clicking the content URL link provided, I get the following error where I'm not able to view the file or download.

[FileInfoCard invalid link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Ibf.png)

The code I'm using is the same as the File Upload Bot example other than I've changed the file type to a PDF document on my web server.

Any ideas as to why the link it not valid?  Some permissions maybe?

```
private CompletableFuture<Void> sendFileCard(
        TurnContext turnContext, String filename, long filesize
    ) { 
        
        Map<String, String> consentContext = new HashMap<>();
        consentContext.put("filename", filename);

        FileConsentCard fileCard = new FileConsentCard();
        fileCard.setDescription("This is the file I want to send you");
        fileCard.setSizeInBytes(filesize);
        fileCard.setAcceptContext(consentContext);
        fileCard.setDeclineContext(consentContext);

        Attachment asAttachment = new Attachment();
        asAttachment.setContent(fileCard);
        asAttachment.setContentType(FileConsentCard.CONTENT_TYPE);
        asAttachment.setName(filename);     

        Activity reply = turnContext.getActivity().createReply();
        reply.setAttachments(Collections.singletonList(asAttachment));

        return turnContext.sendActivityBlind(reply);
    }
```

```
private CompletableFuture<ResultPair<String>> upload(
        FileConsentCardResponse fileConsentCardResponse
    ) {
        AtomicReference<ResultPair<String>> result = new AtomicReference<>();       
        
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            Map<String, String> context = (Map<String, String>) fileConsentCardResponse
                .getContext();
            File filePath = new File("files", context.get("filename"));
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {               
                
                URL url = new URL(fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getUploadUrl());
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Long.toString(filePath.length()));
                connection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Range",
                    String.format("bytes 0-%d/%d", filePath.length() - 1, filePath.length())
                );              

                try (
                    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                    OutputStream uploadStream = connection.getOutputStream()
                ) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytes_read;
                    while ((bytes_read = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {                      
                        uploadStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
                    }                   
                }

                result.set(new ResultPair<String>(true, null));
            } catch (Throwable t) {             
                result.set(new ResultPair<String>(false, t.getLocalizedMessage()));
            } finally {                 
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        })
            .thenApply(aVoid -> result.get());
    }
```

```
private CompletableFuture<Void> fileUploadCompleted(
        TurnContext turnContext, FileConsentCardResponse fileConsentCardResponse
    ) {
        FileInfoCard downloadCard = new FileInfoCard();
        downloadCard.setUniqueId(fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getUniqueId());
        downloadCard.setFileType(fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getFileType());

        Attachment asAttachment = new Attachment();
        asAttachment.setContent(downloadCard);
        asAttachment.setContentType(FileInfoCard.CONTENT_TYPE);
        asAttachment.setName(fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getName());        
        
        asAttachment.setContentUrl(fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getContentUrl());

        Activity reply = MessageFactory.text(
            String.format(
                "<b>File uploaded.</b> Your file <b>%s</b> is ready to download",
                fileConsentCardResponse.getUploadInfo().getName()
            )
        );
        reply.setTextFormat(TextFormatTypes.XML);
        reply.setAttachment(asAttachment);

        return turnContext.sendActivityBlind(reply);
    }
```

I'm not getting any exceptions during the upload process, and it shows a file was created in my OneDrive but it's not available or empty.

[OneDrive activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBdcG.png)

Comment: We are also tried the same, but it is working fine from our end.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/93527375/233080600-e2371d7b-9f46-4669-bd25-4d574c97f062.mp4
Could you please try to upload the other file?

Comment: It appears the issue occurs when files are uploaded directly to a teams site. 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hmm-looks-like-this-file-doesnt-have-a-preview-we/a3e77c84-356f-402a-9fff-cde013a48c25